# Clustering commercial information using K-means for visual mapping

Tags: javascript, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, k-means

I'm trying to perform clustering on small datasets shown to end-users:

```
[
  [1.76, 81, 5, 0],
  [2.99, 72, 5, 0],
  [11.17, 420, 4.8, 0],
  [1.76, 53, 5, 0],
  [16.73, 3403, 5, 0],
  ... // 20 entries per user
]
```

Columns are 1) retail price, 2) fulfilled orders, 3) rating and 4) shipping respectively.
I want to cluster this data into several groups to visualize it on JS frontend.

I'm using ecStat for echarts and it does work but is constantly changing results.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Thus I can't visualize it properly, since I am using size/color visual mapping based on clusters.
Like here we have 3 most cheap items with highest rating of green color and max radius, 5 items of medium price and yellowish color, 8 items of red color and minimal size, and so on.

Is it possible to get 'stable' results within 'set' clusters?
Is it even a viable idea to use k-means and such tools for clustering items with lowest price, highest ratings, number of orders, etc.

How should one approach such tasks in general? Any advice is very appreciated!

Comment: why don't you use **D3** and separate the clusters as you need? D3 would allow you to pivot vector points to a custom canvas. 

It's a bit unclear what you mean by *stable* results. You gotta ask yourself why you want to use clusters in the first place, like what value would that specific type of visualization would provide? 

Personally I think that Partitioning clustering and Clustering validation statistics might do better for this type of commerce data.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I mean 'stable' clustering results don't change over the next invoking of a k-mean function. If price X with rating X1 belong to cluster 1, then it can be mapped to certain size and color. If price X belongs to cluster 1, then 4, then 0, then 5 (even if clusterisation was made correctly) I just can't use such data to meaningfully separate them using visual mapping techniques.

Comment: @ZombieChowder D3 for me feels like overkill here. Main issue for me here is data clustering. Just can't think of an algorithm to group prices based on several factors and get same clustering representation (lowest prices to the first cluster, highest prices to the last) over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means begins with a random initialization by default.

If you don't want that, you can, e.g.,

1. Use a stable algorithm instead
2. Choose the previous centers as starting points

Unstable (except for permutation) results usually indicate suboptimal clustering. K-means is also sensitive to scale. So it probably does not make sense to just use it on the data you have there. You need to *understand* what it does, and how you need to prepare your data to get useful results.